# How to write xpath for the text without html tag/attribute

Tags: xpath, protractor

[enter image description here][1]

```html
<mat-chip role="option" cdkdrag="" container="body" class="cdk-drag mat-chip mat-focus-indicator mat-primary mat-standard-chip mat-chip-with-trailing-icon ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" style="" xpath="1"><div class="mat-chip-ripple"></div> Table data <mat-icon role="img" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="icon-drag-doubledot" class="mat-icon notranslate icon-drag material-icons mat-icon-no-color" data-mat-icon-type="font"></mat-icon><mat-icon role="img" matchipremove="" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="icon-close" class="mat-icon notranslate mat-chip-remove mat-chip-trailing-icon icon-close material-icons mat-icon-no-color" data-mat-icon-type="font"></mat-icon></mat-chip>
```

From the above HTML tags, i want to extract those Table Data text. I am unable to get the text using below xpath

```
//mat-chip[@role='option']//div
//mat-chip[@role='option']//div/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

while executing it's throwing an error 'Failed: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//mat-chip[@role='option']//div/following-sibling::text()[2]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.'

Can anyone please help

[enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, the text belongs to this element `//mat-chip[@role='option']`

I checked it locally, all good. If doesn't work on your end then the problem somewhere else

---

P.S. proof

[image]

Comment: `//mat-chip[@role='option']` will not give text **Sales Level 1**.

Comment: then sentence #2 of my answer @user13892484 believe it or not

Comment: I can even attach a proof

Comment: Oh..that's cool. Can you provide me code snipped which you have tried. Actually, I am using Protractor tool and using xpath to get the text. I am using below code snippet, unfortunately, not working `let txt= element(by.xpath("//mat-chip[@role='option']")).getText();
        console.log(txt)`

Comment: okay, that's a little different from what the question's objective is. We know the xpath is correct now. What do you get as output of your code though? an error the element is not present? or it just prints an empty string?

Comment: I am getting **undefined** output while I am executing below code snippet. `element(by.css("mat-chip[role='option']")).isPresent().then(function (params) {
                let temp=params.innerText;
                console.log("#######"+temp)
            })`

Comment: Why I am getting `undefined` when I running code in protractor. But when I use Javaeditor I am able to get Sales Level 1. I am trying different ways in Protractor but no use. Can you please try in Protractor and help me out!!

Comment: enter image description here added image in my original post

Comment: you don't need to use `innerText` this is a property available in browser and has nothing to do about protractor. You should go with `getText()`

Comment: you actually have 4 mistakes in your code. It'll take me forever to explain each. I did my best to answer the initial question and comply the correct xpath. For everything else open another question

Comment: Sergey, I got solution. Based on above solution which you had provided , similarly i used tagName in Protractor. Hence, I have resolved the issue. Thank you

Comment: great! feel free to ping me with another questions you may have down the road. Just open a question and tag my name in comments with `@`

Answer (score 0):

Selenium expects an element not a text()-node. So use this:
You need this:

```
//mat-chip[@role='option']/div
```

Although I doubt that [@role='option'] has any benefits.

If you are certain that there will be only one div inside that mat-chip, you could speed up the XPath by adding [1], like this:

```
//mat-chip[@role='option']/div[1]
```

This tells the XPath engine to stop searching after it has found this first div.